# Mac os x software update \ java

Tags: macos

Just some background information, My Macbook Pro OS X broke a couple weeks ago and wouldn't let me onto my laptop, so I hard reset it by erasing the hard drive in disk utility then got the disk from when the laptop was bought (around 2011-12), I installed that disk onto the laptop and everything since then had been running fine.

Then I ran into this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzFq3.png

After doing some research I found out that I obviously needed to update my Mac \ Java as I installed the mac with a earlier version, So as I attempted to update my mac I got This Message,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeZR3.png

If anybody knows how to fix this please do as i've been up late every night trying to save money and fix it than to go to the Apple Store.

Jacob

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, this isn't really a programming question and more of just a general computing use question, perhaps stack overflow isnt the best place to ask questions like that, i'd suggest the mac forums or the stack exchange superuser site instead, good luck though.

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com